# Google AMP URL for dynamic pages with QueryString

Tags: amp-html

I have a non-html page  https://www.youth.sg/Users/S/H/ShermanWong/2017/5/Creating-art-for-Charlie-Lim and when I use the AMP extension installed in my Chrome to verify the AMP page _https://www.youth.sg/sublayouts/YouthSG/Article/ArticleAMPPage.aspx?item=2696c638-2290-4826-aaae-17047a84fb95, it give me no error. However, when I test in _https://search.google.com/search-console/amp, it state that is not a valid AMP page. Anyone can help?

Sorry I can't post 3 links so I have put '_' beside the URL.

Comment: How you are using your URL params say "/Article/ArticleAMPPage.aspx?item=2696c638-2290-4826-aaae-17047a84fb95" for making up amp-html?

I am trying to implement same, but unable to pass this info in my src of amp-list for details page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you run your test at `https://validator.ampproject.org` or put #development=1 at the end of your url and find result in the developer console.

And see this is how your page is not amp valid,

```
https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youth.sg%2Fsublayouts%2FYouthSG%2FArticle%2FArticleAMPPage.aspx%3Fitem%3D2696c638-2290-4826-aaae-17047a84fb95
```

[image]